# c# change combobox button size and image

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a combobox in my winform, and I wish change the button that show the list (with the triangle) with another button or at least change the image..

it's possible? how can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `OwnerDrawn` techniques like the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891981/net-ownerdraw-combobox-vista-7-themed-dropdownlist

or you override the window proc and redefine whole control message handling or you create your own control from scratch or you use third party controls like DevExpress WinForms suite or Telerik ones.